# Многопоточный графический чат на сокетах

Tags: java, javafx

Реализовую чат на сокетах с использованием JavaFX. По неизвестной мне причине метод `public static String getMsg()` (который я вызываю в строке `if(!(string = stageController.getMsg()).isEmpty()`) в `Client.java`) постоянно возвращает пустую строку. Окно состоит из: `TextArea`, `TextField` и `Button`. При нажатии на `Button` отправляется сооб. на сервер, метод `public final void send(ActionEvent actionEvent)` обрабатывает это нажатие.
`Main.java`

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import objects.Server;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
        serverThread.setDaemon(true); // Теперь этот поток будет завершаться при закрытии главного окна
        serverThread.start();

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/dialog.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

`Client.java`

```
package objects;

import controllers.stageController;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    public Client(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        System.out.println("New client connected.\r\n\tInetAdress: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try(InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out))) {

            stageController sc = new stageController();
            String string;

            while(clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                /* По нажатию на кнопку отправлять сообщение серверу */
                if(!(string = stageController.getMsg()).isEmpty()) { // Вот тут я постоянно получаю пустую строку!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    bufferedWriter.write(string);
                    System.out.println("Client has send the message: " + string);
                    stageController.setMsg("");
                }
                /*****************************************************/

                /* Принимать сообщение от сервера */
//                if((string2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
//                    sc.receive(string2 + "\r\n");
//                    System.out.println("Client received the message");
//                }
                /**********************************/
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in Client class!");
        }
    }
}
```

`Server.java`

```
package objects;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Server implements Runnable {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public final static int port = 5555;
    private static Map<String, String> clientInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static List<Client>        clientList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Server() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server created.\r\n\tPort: " + port + "\r\n\tInetAdress: " + serverSocket.getInetAddress());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in server`s constructor");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                Client client = new Client(serverSocket.accept());
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(client);
                clientList.add(client);
                clientThread.setDaemon(true); // Теперь этот поток будет завершаться при закрытии главного окна
                clientThread.start();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in Server.run()");
        }
    }

    public final static void addClient(String login, String parol) {
        clientInfo.put(login, parol);
    }

    public final static boolean isPresent(String login, String parol) {
        return clientInfo.get(login) != null && (clientInfo.get(login)).equals(parol);
    }
}
```

`stageController.java`

```
package controllers;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class stageController {

    @FXML
    private TextArea ta;
    @FXML
    private TextField tf;

    private static String msg;

    static {
        msg = "";
    }

    public static void setMsg(String _msg) {
        msg = _msg;
    }

    public static String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public final void send(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        msg = tf.getText();
        tf.clear();
    }

    public final void receive(String msg) {
        ta.setText(msg + "\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: цикл в клиенте while(clientSocket.isConnected()) будет напрасно использовать ресурсы процессора в активном ожидании stageController.getMsg(). Вам необходимо добавить листенер, который по окончанию ввода текста (нажатия кнопки или чего то там еще) сам отправит сообщение на сервер

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в данном случае в том, что контроллер вы создаете "на пустом месте" вызовом `stageController sc = new stageController();`. Такой код работать не будет в принципе, поскольку `TextField tf` и `TextArea ta` при создании контроллера таким образом не будут существовать в данном объекте (не будут привязаны).

Один из способов получить контроллер с привязанными объектами UI:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/StageView.fxml"));
loader.load();
stageController controller = loader.getController();
```

Подробнее работа с контроллером рассмотрена в этой серии [уроков](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/part2/).

Answer (score 0):

@DaysLikeThis , @Rawnald Gregory Erickson .Учел оба комментария. Почитал в Шилдте как использовать Observer и Observable. Все равно в консоли не сообщается о том, что клиент отправил сообщение. Вот что изменилось:

`Client.java`

```
public class Client implements Observer {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    public Client(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public Socket getClientSocket() {
        return this.clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable obj, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Client has sent the message: " + arg);
    }
}
```

`Server.java`

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public final static int port = 5555;
    private static Map<String, String> clientInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static List<Client>        clientList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Server() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server created.\r\n\tPort: " + port + "\r\n\tInetAdress: " + serverSocket.getInetAddress());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in server`s constructor");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            /* Получить контроллер */
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("../fxml/stage.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            stageController controller = loader.getController();
            /**********************/
            while(true) {
                Client client = new Client(serverSocket.accept());

                System.out.println( "Client " +/* Вывести логин пользователя */ " connected.\r\n" +
                                    "\tInetAdress: " + client.getClientSocket().getInetAddress() );

//                Thread clientThread = new Thread(client);

                controller.addObserver(client);

                clientList.add(client);
//                clientThread.setDaemon(true); // Теперь этот поток будет завершаться при закрытии главного окна
//                clientThread.start();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in Server.run()");
        }
    }

    public final static void addClient(String login, String parol) {
        clientInfo.put(login, parol);
    }

    public final static boolean isPresent(String login, String parol) {
        return clientInfo.get(login) != null && (clientInfo.get(login)).equals(parol);
    }
}
```

`stageController.java`

```
public class stageController extends Observable {
    /*..........................................*/
    public final void send(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(tf.getText().isEmpty())
            return;
        msg = tf.getText();

        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(msg);

        ta.setText(ta.getText() + msg + "\r\n");
        tf.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: В приведенных вами фрагментах кода не видно привязки кнопки к обработчику нажатия, возможно, проблема в этом: метод `send(ActionEvent actionEvent)` просто не вызывается при нажатии на кнопку, тк. не привязан. Для привязки кнопки при инициализации контроллера нужно воспользоваться вот таким вызовом `button.setOnAction(/*Объект EventHandler*/)`. Вообще настоятельно рекомендую вам полностью пройти курс по ссылке из моего ответа, от силы пару дней, но поможет понять концепцию.

Comment: Не видно привязки, потому что она находиться в fxml - файле, код которого я не скинул ибо было бы слишком много текста. Поверьте, первое, что я сделал - это проверил, работает ли обработчик. И он работает, проблема не в этом.